# statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.Infeasible Test Error: The x values include a column with constant values and so the test statistic cannot be computed

Tags: python, excel, flask, statsmodels

This code is taking an excel file as input which has several columns with same value in a column which is causing the error ang giving wrong output. This code works right in jupyter notebook but fails in python file

```
`@app.route('/gct',methods=['POST','GET'])
def gct():
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    # assigned the integer 15 to the variable 'nobs'
    nobs = -15
    #df = df.loc[:, df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) == 1]
    #df = df.iloc[:,0].values
# assigning the last 15 observations to the variable 'X_test', while the rest will be assigned to the variable 'X_train'
    X_train, X_test = df[0:-nobs], df[-nobs:]
    #X_train.columns = X_train.columns.str.strip()
    result = granger.granger_causation_matrix(X_train, variables=X_train.columns)
    print("gct")
    return render_template("gct.html",output=X_train)

I tried X_train.columns = X_train.columns.str.strip()`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have to mention what is the error you are getting and also provide sample data to reproduce the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the columns in your dataframe consist of only a single value and the test does not support this. Try removing the columns that only have one value. To find the columns try:

```
for k,v in df.nunique().items():
   if v == 1:
      print(k,v)
```